# Converting a .mat file to cv image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, conv-neural-network

I have a `.mat` file and want to convert it into a CV image format such that I can use it for a CNN model.

I am trying to obtain an RGB/ other colored image and not gray.

I tried doing the following(below) but I get a grayscale image, but when I plot the actual mat file using matplotlib it is not grayscale. Also, the `.mat` file has a `px_spacing` array apart from the image array. I am not sure how this is helpful.

```
def mat_to_image(mat_image):
    f = loadmat(mat_image,appendmat=True)
    image = np.array(f.get('I')).astype(np.float32)
    mean = image.mean()
    std= image.std()
    print(mean, std)
    hi = np.max(image)
    lo = np.min(image)
    image = (((image - lo)/(hi-lo))*255).astype(np.uint8)
    im = Image.fromarray(image,mode='RGB')
    return im
images=mat_to_image(dir/filename)
cv_img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(images), cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
```

Normally plotting the `.mat` file fetches a non-grayscale(RGB image)

```
imgplot= plt.imshow(loadmat(img,appendmat=True).get('I'))
plt.show()
```

Here is how the mat file looks after `print(loadmat('filename'))`

```
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Mon Sep  9 11:32:54 2019',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'I': array([
     [  81,   75,   74,   75,  -11,   14,   49,   37,   29,  -24, -183, -349, -581, -740],
     [  51,   33,   67,   36,    1,   42,   30,   49,   47,   42,   14, -85, -465, -727],
     [  23,   31,   36,   20,   54,   70,   44,   56,   56,   79,   62, 19, -204, -595],
     [   7,   12,   36,   47,   59,   68,   74,   56,   59,  100,   74, 34,   -3, -353],
     [  23,   19,   51,   87,   86,   79,   91,   76,   96,   95,   52, 51,   74, -141],
     [  18,   51,   54,   97,   93,   94,   98,   83,  119,   71,   36, 69,   50,  -16],
     [ -10,    5,   53,   92,   69,   87,  103,  114,  118,   77,   51, 68,   30,    0],
     [ -24,   11,   74,   80,   49,   68,  106,  129,  107,   63,   57, 70,   39,   -1],
     [ -45,   43,   83,   69,   43,   64,   98,  108,   90,   35,   27, 55,   31,  -13],
     [  -9,   32,   83,   78,   66,  106,   89,   85,   58,   43,   31, 39,   28,    7],
     [  45,   35,   76,   45,   51,   84,   55,   66,   49,   41,   39, 28,   13,   -7],
     [  85,   67,   61,   45,   69,   53,   23,   32,   31,  -12,  -34, -182, -376, -425],
     [ 136,   93,   71,   54,   30,   39,   17,  -21,  -29,  -43, -101, -514, -792, -816]
     ], dtype=int16),
 'px_spacing': array([[0.78125]])}
```

Comment: I think `imshow` plots a color image just because of the default color map (`rcParams["image.cmap"]` which is usually `'viridis'` ). The image itself has just one channel.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: I have another doubt. What is the use of px_spacing. Can it be somehow used to change the image resolution?

Comment: I don't know, it's not described in the [spec](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf)

Comment: I meant if you could see the details of the mat file I have given above. You could see a px_spacing : array([[0.78125]]). I want to know if this could be used to make changes in the image

Comment: I *think* the px_spacing is the pixel spacing and hence will determin the size of the image when printed, but all this won't help you here: in the end you have just 13x14 values so there's no way to extract any color information or additional pixels to get a higher resolution.